# what is the Algorithm in java complementation

Tags: java, implementation

We will talk about complementation in java.

**m % n.**
for example:
10 % 3 = 1;

As we know, when n is 2 N-th power, m & n will be more efficient. 
What I want to know is how java implement "%", how to calculate 10 % 3. 
When I know it, I can compare the efficiency between "%" and "&".

Comment: My guess is, the JIT compiler maps `%` to the corresponding processor instruction. I'm not sure, but it seems logical.

Comment: Have you read [**Chapter 15.17.3 Remainder Operator %**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3) of the JLS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integer remainder computation is implemented with a CPU instruction. The CPU may implement it in hardware or in microcode - depends on the hardware where you run the code. The bitwise and operator is much simpler to implement in hardware so you'll probably find it faster, but it's impossible to say by how much.

This is the same for interpreted and JIT compiled Java code; interpreted just has more overhead.

Floating point remainder and a 64 bit "long" remainder on a 32 bit architecture are a different  beast altogether.